# Float con un decimal sin redondear C++

Tags: c++

Un saludo cordial a todos.

Necesito ayuda, quiero que un numero por ejemplo 0.57, se exprese como 0.5.

es decir con solo un decimal sin redondear. Eh podido expresar con un decimal pero se redondea, por ejemplo: 0.57, se expresa en 0.6.

¿Qué código tengo que usar?

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: A ver si `floor()` te deja. Pasate por el [tour] para que aprendas el funcionamiento básico del sitio y vuelve cargado con [ask] cuando tengas un problema :)

Comment: Hola Ariel, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Aunque la pregunta es interesante y se ajusta bien a la temática del sitio, sería ideal que añadieras algo más de detalle y/o código con lo que hayas intentado y los problemas/dificultades que te estés encontrando. Lee [ask] para más información y consejos, y completa el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio en general (y ganar tu primera medalla). Saludos.

Comment: con que código has intentado?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes controlar el estilo de redondeo de números en coma flotante con:

- [`FE_DOWNWARD`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_round): redondeo a la baja.
- [`FE_TONEAREST`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_round): redondeo al número representable más cercano.
- [`FE_TOWARDZERO`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_round): redondeo hacia cero.
- [`FE_UPWARD`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_round): redondeo al alza.

En combinación con la función [`std::fesetround`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/feround), todo perteneciente a la cabecera [`<cfenv>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cfenv). Dado que necesitas redondear a la baja, usa dicha función así:

```
auto f = 0.57f;
std::cout << f << '\n'; // Muestra 0.57
std::cout << std::setprecision(1) << f << '\n'; // Muestra 0.6

std::fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD); // Aplicamos el redondeo a la baja
std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << f << '\n'; // Muestra 0.56
std::cout << std::setprecision(1) << f << '\n'; // Muestra 0.5
```

Comment: Hola, oye sería bueno que cambies las referencias de *cppreference* a su versión en inglés. Por ejemplo, ahora mismo el link sobre la cabecera `<cfenv>` no contiene nada.

Comment: Gracias por el aviso @Xam , solucionado.

Answer (score 0):

En C++ otra solución puede ser

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float num = 0.57;
    cout<<floor(10*num)/10<< endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/HJqLl0rOM)

Comment: Es recomendable añadir explicación de lo que realiza el código y que mejora, saludos.

Comment: Lo tendre en cuenta.....saludos.